# Calculating the limit of a sum

Tags: real-analysis

$g(y)=y+y^3+y^9+y^{27}+...$

How to calculate $lim_{y \rightarrow 1^-} g(y)$?
I know that the answer is infinity, but how can one prove that?
If $h(y)=1+y+y^2+y^3+y^{4}+..., g(y) \leq h(y)$ and I know that $lim_{y \rightarrow 1-} h(y) = \infty $, and also $g(y)$ is a subsequence of it.

Comment: $g(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y^{3^{n}}$, and $\lim_{y \rightarrow 1} y^{3^{n}}=1$

Answer (score 1):

For any
$g(y)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y^{a_n}
$
where $a_n$ is an increasing sequence of positive integers,
for any $m$,
if $0 < y < 1$,
$g(y)
\gt \sum_{n=0}^m y^{a_n}
\ge my^{a_m}
$.

If
$y > 1-\dfrac1{a_m^2}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
y^{a_m}
&\gt (1-\dfrac1{a_m^2})^{a_m}\\
&= ((1-\dfrac1{a_m^2})^{a_m^2})^{1/a_m}\\
&\approx (1/e)^{1/a_m}\\
&= \dfrac1{e^{1/a_m}}\\
&\approx \dfrac1{1+1/a_m}
\qquad\text{since } a_m \to \infty\\
&\gt \dfrac12\\
\end{array}
$

so
$g(y)
\gt \dfrac{m}{2}
$
so
$g(y)
\to \infty
$.